# How to filter out items from redux state in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am getting data from my backend where I get list of product and assign it to `cartList` state in redux reducer. And here I am trying to filter out the item which contain both of the field `item.teamWith === 0 && item.priceType === "TEAM"` and assigning filtered value to waitingList. But the problem is i tried several times but i don't see any value assigned to it. this is how my code looks like.

> Code

```
const initialState = {
  isFetching: false,
  cartList: [],
  waitingItem: [],
  page: null,
  fetched: false,
  fetchError: null
};
 case actionTypes.GET_CART_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        cartList: action.payload._embedded.cartResourceList,
        page: action.payload.page,
        waitingItem: state.cartList.filter(item => item.teamWith === 0 && item.priceType === "TEAM"),
        fetched: true,
        isFetching: false,
      };
```

[image: appimage]

Here `waitingItem` is not even available in my state. I don't know Why. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are assigning the `waitingItem` based on `cartList` returned by API response and filtering it accordingly. So, instead of using existing state which is not yet updated to set waitingItem, you need to use the actual payload, like this:

```
case actionTypes.GET_CART_SUCCESS:
      const cartList= action.payload._embedded.cartResourceList;
      const waitingItem = cartList.filter(item => item.teamWith === 0 && item.priceType === "TEAM");

      return {
        ...state,
        cartList,
        page: action.payload.page,
        waitingItem:waitingItem,
        fetched: true,
        isFetching: false,
      };
```

Answer (score 0):

From your code

```js
state.cartList.filter(item => item.teamWith === 0 && item.priceType === "TEAM")
```

and image, where `cartList` properties are present, there are no properties you are filtering by - `teamWith` and `priceType`, so you need to alter you `filter` function or logic.

Probably, when `waitingItem` is empty array, undefined or something like this Redux doesn't add it to state...